# What determines which capabilities are enumerated by the MediaStreamTrack.getCapabilities() method?

Tags: getusermedia

I have been working on an application of getUserMedia and WebRTC that requires me to make use of information returned by the **getConstraints()**, **getCapabilities()**, and **getSettings()** methods of a MediaStreamTrack.

In testing, using **getCapabilities()** on the track corresponding to an external webcam might return something like...

```
aspectRatio: {max: 1920, min: 0.000925925925925926}
deviceId: ""
exposureCompensation: MediaSettingsRange {max: 2047, min: 3, step: 1}
exposureMode: (2) ["manual", "continuous"]
facingMode: []
focusMode: (2) ["manual", "continuous"]
frameRate: {max: 30, min: 1}
groupId: ""
height: {max: 1080, min: 1}
whiteBalanceMode: ["manual"]
width: {max: 1920, min: 1}
zoom: MediaSettingsRange {max: 5, min: 1, step: 1}
```

...but if `focusDistance` or `colorTemperature` (or other potential members listed [here](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-image/#mediatracksupportedconstraints-members)) are not in the capabilities list, then what determines the controllable settings for a camera or other media device?

Would the answer to this also apply to mobile devices, such as Android or iOS tablets or phones, that have integrated cameras and microphones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capabilities returned by `track.getCapabilities()` are the intersection of four things:

1. The track source. `getUserMedia` and `getDisplayMedia` tracks have different capabilities.
2. The `track.kind`. E.g. audio capabilities are not returned for video tracks, and vice versa.
3. The capabilities supported by the browser.
4. The capabilities supported by the device.

You learn what capabilities the browser supports like this:

```js
console.log(navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints());
```

You then typically rely on documentation and specification to know which capabilities apply to which method and `kind`.

Newer versions of browsers tend to support more capabilities. Not all browsers support `getCapabilities()` yet. Firefox, for instance, does not [yet](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1179084), even though it otherwise supports constraints.

For this reason, it is always best to check what's supported—as shown above—before relying on a capability.

To the specific capabilities you mention, `focusDistance` and `colorTemperature`, they are defined for tracks returned by `getUserMedia`, but defined in the mediacapture-image extension spec, so they should show up if they're supported. Their absence means they're not supported.

Comment: Good answer! Thanks.